# Are there any heroes skills that can pass through fissure?

Tags: dota-2, dota

Taking *blinks* aside, are there any heroes skills that can pass through **Earthshaker's** **road block** from *Fissure*?

Comment: Please don't use tags for games that are not relevant to your question.

Comment: They are related.

Comment: It doesn't matter. Your question appears to be about Dota 2 (from a quick Google search). Do not include a game tag if your question is not about that game (and only rarely, if ever, should you include other tags).

Comment: **Both** games shares the same game mechanics. Even HoN had the same Hero.

Comment: As far as I can tell, even though the games are similar, they are not the same. Specifically, you seem to be asking for the set of hero skills that can pass through the road block created by Fissure, and the universe from which that set can be chosen depends on the game. The games are more similar than I realized, but I still think it would be better to ask about just one game.

Comment: I already removed HoN tag. But as far as Dota and Dota2, they're basically the same.

Comment: @MegaNairda While they may be *basically* the same, they are two separate games, from two separate developers, therefore, your question should only be tagged with one of them.

Comment: If you're saying Dota1 and Dota2 should be separate, then you're absolutely wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stated that heroes that has Blink Dagger or Force Staff can avoid a fissure block, I will not list, as requested, heroes with *blink* or *teleport* capabilities like, for example, Anti-Mage/Queen of Pain or Nature's Prophet/Wisp.

Heroes that can pass Fissure alone

- **Batrider** using *FireFly*
- **Faceless Void** using *Time Walk*
- **Mirana** using *Leap*
- **Morphling** using *Waveform*
- **Puck** using *Illusory Orb*
- **Sandking** using *Burrow Strike*
- **Spectre** using *Spectral Dagger*
- **Storm Spirit** using *Ball Lightning*

Heroes that can pass Fissure it there is an enemy (or ally in some case) on the other side

- **Chaos Knight** using *Reality Rift* on an enemy on the other side
- **Huskar** using *Life Break* on an enemy on the other side
- **Phatom Assassin** using *Phantom Strike* on an enemy/ally on the other side
- **Riki** using *Blink Strike* on an enemy on the other side
- **Spirit Breaker** using *Charge of Darkness* on an enemy/ally in the direction
- **Vengeful Spirit** using *Nether Swap* on an enemy on the other side
- **Clockwerk** using *Hookshot* on an enemy/ally on the other side

Honorable mention

- **Tiny** can *Toss* and ally on the other side if there is an enemy there

For sure I forgot someone, I will recheck this later on.

Comment: Timbersaw's timber chain, Pudge's hook, Sprit breaker's nether strike

Comment: I believe that broodmother should be able to walk over a fissure, but I haven't tested it, and can't find a reference to it in the wiki.

Answer (score 1):

Easier to create a new answer than edit. Feel free to combine into yours:

Affects Self:

- Clockwerk - Hookshot
- Huskar - Life Break
- Wisp - Tether and Relocate
- Sand King - Burrowstrike
- Spirit Breaker - Charge
- Chaos Knight - Reality Rift
- Magnus - Skewer
- Anti-Mage - Blink
- Mirana - Leap
- Morphling - Waveform
- Riki - Blink Strike
- Vengful Spirit - Nether Swap
- Faceless Void - Time Walk
- Phantom Assassin - Phantom Strike
- Spectre - Spectral Dagger
- Slark - Pounce
- Puck - Ethereal Jaunt
- Storm Spirit - Ball Lightning
- Nature's Prophet - Teleport
- Queen of Pain - Blink
- Batrider - Firefly

Affects others:

- Dark Seer - Vaccuum can pull units over
- Batrider - Flamebreak can push units over
- Invoker - Deafening Blast can push units over
- Beastmaster - Roar can push units over

Comment: OP's post states "Taking blinks aside".

Comment: @Kotsu True. The vast majority of these skills would be considered blinks or pseudo-blinks, however. It's simpler to just be thorough.

Comment: @Decency Have you really tried Morphling Waveform passing through the fissure road block? I'm not pretty sure but I do recall being unable to pass through it using waveform.

Comment: @MegaNairda It would very much surprise me if you couldn't. The way I went about making the list was just thinking of what spells allow you to pass over cliffs, as I believe Fissure is treated in exactly the same way. I'm positive that Morphling can move over cliffs with Waveform.

Comment: Nature prophets teleport is actually a telport which nothing to deal with blocking paths